# How to subtract from current field in mongodb with update using aggregation pipeline?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Basically I want to subtract the value from total and update it by subtracted value.

```
db.invoice.update({ "_id": ObjectId(req.params.id) },
    { "$set": { "total": total - 200 } }, function (err, doc) {
        if (err) return new Error(err);
        if (doc.result.n > 0) {
            console.log(" Invoice updated with Payment info.", doc.result);
        } else {
            console.log("Something went wrong while payment info updation.")
        }
});
```

I don't know how to achieve this here. I found $mul operator for multiplication  with current field
 but I didn't find $sub operator in mongodb. 
I found $subtract aggregation but I am unable to use $subtract with update().

Could someone help me? Please

Thanks

Answer (score 21):

You can use $inc operator with the negative value.

```
db.invoice.update({ "_id": ObjectId(req.params.id) },
    { "$inc": { "total": -200 } }, function (err, doc) {
        if (err) return new Error(err);
        if (doc.result.n > 0) {
            console.log(" Invoice updated with Payment info.", doc.result);
        } else {
            console.log("Something went wrong while payment info updation.")
        }
});
```

Comment: Thanks it worked , but can't i use aggregation with update ?

Comment: You can but it was the easiest way.